# wanted America out

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Polling as recently as on August 9th has shown that, if asked to express a view, Americans said they supported Mr Biden’s withdrawal. The left within the Democratic party **wanted America out** long ago, and his establishment Democratic critics have no other political home.

Source: The Economist

What does "wanted America out" mean? The best guess I got now is "wanted America to be more active in dealing with foreign affairs."  Not sure I am on the right track.

Comment: Have you heard that **America** has taken its military forces **out** of Afghanistan this week?

Comment: want somebody or something out [of a place.]

Answer (score 3):

You don't show the context, but this is presumably talking about Afghanistan. The left wanted America **out of Afghanistan** long ago.

Comment: Got it. Thank you both.   Does "his establishment Democratic critics" mean "his dominant group among the Democratic critics"?

Comment: Not necessarily; "establishment" refers to "the important and powerful people who control a country or an organization, especially those who support the existing situation" ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/establishment)) - ie the mainstream people who control the Democratic party, as opposed to the "left" referred to earlier.